# Problem using ur5/ur10 with moveit in indigo

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-industrial, universal-robot, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I was using the universal robot package with ros hydro on ubuntu 12.04. I felt like it was time to upgrade my linux and ros versions. I am now running ros indigo on ubuntu 14.04.

When I try to use the moveit planner with a UR10, no solutions are found... Can anybody help ? Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202126/problem-using-ur5/ur10-with-moveit-in-indigo/) by [Deen Cockburn](https://answers.ros.org/users/21532/deen-cockburn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-01-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This could perhaps be a recently reported issue with MoveIt under Indigo. See [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/moveit-users/M71T-GaUNgg) moveit-users post for more info, and [ros-industrial/universal_robot#156](https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot/pull/156) for some candidate changes to work around/solve this.

Could you try those changes out and see if things start working for you?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0